# Retrieving value from boolean fails

Tags: c#, mysql

```
mConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False; server=localhost;database=FichasReparacao;uid=root");
mConn.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT blacklist FROM Cliente where ID =@id", mConn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbid.Text);

//Executa a Query SQL
blist = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(blist));
mConn.Close();
```

I have this piece of code, I'm testing it and for that I pick  the blacklist (boolean) value from table Cliente where the ID It's what I choose. And show it in a messagebox, thing is, I have 0 , 1 and null values and when I try to show it on the MessageBox it will always show 'TRUE'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are using ExecuteNonQuery on a SELECT query, this doesn't work because the only result returned by [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) on this kind of statement is -1. (See Remarks section in the link provided)

If your query returns only one row then:

```
blist = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

However a bit of precaution is necessary. If the query doesn't return anything (i.e. no ID found) then the conversion to boolean will fail because [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) will return null.

So the correct approach is:

```
object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
blist = (result == null ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(result));
```

You can change the default value in case of null to true instead of false if it makes more sense for you

Answer (score 0):

use `command.ExecuteScalar()` to fetch a value from a `SELECT` statement.